# comparing client timestamp with server timestamp

Tags: javascript, ajax, timestamp

I have a problem with my timestamp code.

```
<script>
    var cTime = Date.now() / 1000|0;
    setInterval(function () {
        getServerTime( cTime );
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

and getServerTime looks like this:

```
function getServerTime(cTime){
    $.ajax({
        url: "func/timestamp.php",
        success: function(result) {
            var sTime = parseInt(result);

            if ( sTime > cTime ){
                cTime = Date.now() / 1000|0;
                console.log("The client Timestamp has been updated.");
            }else{
                console.log("The client Timestamp is uptodate.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But it seems like "cTime" inside the  tags never gets updated, as it should... is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing in the value `cTime` you are in effect creating a local variable with the same name as your global var. It is this local variable that is being updated from within `getServerTime`

Try defining `function getServerTime(cTime)`

simply as `function getServerTime()`